# editing a document, saves as a new document

Tags: xpages

From a dynamic view controller, click link to EDIT a document, when I submit it creates a NEW document, not simply updating the one I clicked.   What setting could I have set wrong?  The URL even says "editdocument" when editing the view.

Comment: Show us your data source properties for the XPage used when opening/editing the document

Comment: Hi Per, not sure exactly how to do that....the xpage data source is simply 'document1' and the default action is 'Create document' but another xpage does not have this issue...it has an additional data source of 'view1', which I think is a mistake.  Here is the XML:

<xp:this.data>
  <xp:dominoDocument
   formName="PARequest"
   var="document1">
   <xp:this.postOpenDocument><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument();
var sUNID = doc.getUniversalID();
sessionScope.unid = sUNID;}]]>
   </xp:this.postOpenDocument>
  </xp:dominoDocument>
 </xp:this.data>

Comment: So frustrating while learning this.    It WAS creating a new document, but now it seems to be creating conflicts, which show in Notes but not on the XPage representation of the view.    Then, a categorized view (first column categorizing upcoming deadline dates..."within 1 week" vs "within 2 weeks", etc.... is not calculating correctly after edits)

Comment: it just occurred to me that maybe the NEW document is the conflict, and the xpage view shows it as a regular document, as opposed to what I have gotten use to for 30 years in Notes views

Comment: SOLUTION: from the hint I got from your question, plus more searching on stackoverflow, I found where I had an extra "this.data" block in the source...not sure how I put that there, but I must have.   It's all working now.  Thank you Per Henrik

Comment: great to hear 

Comment: Matt, I added an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify your data source properties on the XPage used when opening/editing the document.